# PlantUML not recognizing .sysml extension anymore in Eclipse

Tags: plantuml, sysml

PlantUML used to recognize the .sysml extension for SysML v2. Then I updated the PlantUML eclipse plugin.

My installation details show "PlantUML Feature" version 1.1.29 and "PlantUML Library Feature" version 1.2023.10". It seems like the updated PlantUML works fine with programs with the .puml extension (as it did with the older version), but no longer recognizes SysML v2 files. This is true even if I change the extension from .sysml to .puml.

How can this be fixed e.g. it works with the newer PlantUML, .puml files and .sysml2 files like it used to.

I tried updating to the latest PlantUML plugin in Eclipse. I have two update sites:

1. PlantUML-SysMLv2 P2 Site All Versions: https://github.com/himi/p2-update-puml-sysmlv2/raw/main/updates and
2. PlantUML composite site: https://hallvard.github.io/plantuml/

I did do install from Eclipse marketplace originally. I get no errors when I "Check for Updates".